# Are there analytical solutions for the polynomial $\alpha K x^\alpha + x -N = 0$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I'm interesting in finding analytical solutions for the equation 
$$\alpha K x^\alpha + x -N = 0,$$
where $\alpha$ is a positive integer and both $K$ and $N$ are positive real constants.

Based on the meaning of the equation (derived from a problem in chemistry), there must be one (and only one) real solution between zero and $N$. Actually, I'm interested in only such solution, not any other outside the $(0, \, N)$ range.

I know that I can use numerical methods to solve for specific $\alpha$, $N$ and $K$. I'm seeking a more elegant method.

I also know that no general solution for a general polynomial of order 5 or more can exist, but maybe this one falls in some special case I'm not aware of.

I'm a chemist, so I apology if the question is malformed. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: There are closed-form power series (obtained by change of variable from 
the power series of the inverse function of $y (1-y)^t$, for which see e.g. 
http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan.pdf or 
http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan2.pdf); 
if memory serves, these can be expressed as hypergeometric functions when 
$\alpha$ is an integer.  But indeed no solution in radicals for $\alpha>4$
and general $N,K$.

Comment: The power series in powers of $K$ is
$$x = N - \alpha N^\alpha K + \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{1+j} N^{j\alpha - j+1} (-K)^j}{(j-1)!} \prod_{i=1}^{j-2} (j\alpha-i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $\alpha K$ we obtain a polynomial equation of the form $$x^{\alpha} + d_1x + d_0=0.$$

Already for $\alpha=5$ it is known that such an equation (called in *Bring-Jerrard normal form*) is *not* solvable by radicals for general $d_0$, $d_1$. A solution of the Bring-Jerrard quintic in terms of hypergeometric functions can be found in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form).

Comment: Ok, many thanks. So I can safely say there is no easy solution for general $\alpha$.

Comment: @Simone Conti: Everything depends on what you mean by "analytic". If this word has a usual meaning, then an analytic solution is given in the comment of Robert Israel.